# Which hibernate Bulk-id strategy to use for Oracle when you can’t use temporary tables

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Hibernate is generating temporary tables for JOINED inheritance, however oracle user does not  privileges to create/delete table, therefore we are using InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy to omit temp table creation. My question is, is this the best option for Oracle? 
What are the differences between InlineIdsOrClauseBulkIdStrategy and InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy performance wise?

Comment: Did you go the answer to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You will find at the bottom of [this page](https://in.relation.to/2017/02/01/non-temporary-table-bulk-id-strategies/), in the conclusion paragraph, [the answer](https://in.relation.to/2017/02/01/non-temporary-table-bulk-id-strategies/) to your question.

You also have the [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-bulk-hql-strategies) of hibernate tacling the subject of [bulk strategies](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-bulk-hql-strategies):

I hope this answer your question.